# Random JSON where x is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file (https://api.myjson.com/bins/o7s1v) and I want to use javascript to get a random object where a condition is met for example a random object where "egg-group-1" is equal to "monster".

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you share your code as well?

Comment: *How would I go about doing this?* run a loop on the list. In every iteration, match properties for *where* clause. If matched, push it to another list. Not generate a random number such that its greater than 0 and less than newList.length and Ta-Da!!!

Comment: Please put all relevant code _into the question itself_. Remember, links rot.

Comment: This will solve your partial problem: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=filter+objects+based+on+property+javascript+stack+overflow

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to find the first match, use find(), if you want to find a random one, you could use filter() and then access a random element:

```js
let arr = [{"id":1,"dex":1,"form":"null","mon":"Bulbasaur","type1":"Grass","type2":"Poison","egg-group-1":"Monster","egg-group-2":"Grass","legend":"FALSE","gen":1},{"id":2,"dex":2,"form":"null","mon":"Ivysaur","type1":"Grass","type2":"Poison","egg-group-1":"Monster","egg-group-2":"Grass","legend":"FALSE","gen":1}];

let first = arr.find(v => v['egg-group-1'] === 'Monster'); // will return the first one
console.log(first);

let random = arr.filter(v => v['egg-group-1'] === 'Monster');
console.log(random[Math.floor(Math.random()*random.length)]);
```

Comment: Please let OP share effort. There are so many posts that shows how to filter object array based on attribute

Comment: So this is why you downvote correct answers? Go read the help center and related meta posts about your missbehaviour! @Rajesh

Comment: There is a reason you have *close as duplicate* in closing option. Filtering an array is a very obvious query answered multiple times. You should choose to mark it as duplicate instead of answering. Also `downvote`  does not mean correctness. Its for incorrect or not required.

Comment: Show me a exact duplicate and I will close with the dupehammer - I didn't find one. The question is not about filtering only, but about filtering and accessing a random element of the found ones. You obviously didn't really understand @Rajesh

Comment: @Rajesh Since I am new to JSON as a whole I searched for posts that answer my question but as you can probably tell from my lack of using it in the question filtering was a term I did not think applied to this context.

Comment: @JoshuaLavelle Its alright. Remember to share your code/effort in your question. That will help us to help you with more that just correct code. Also try to break your problem. Your problem had 2 parts: 1. Filter Objects based on property. 2. Get random object from given list. If you try to split problem, you will get solution easily.

Comment: _more than just correct code_ What's that? What else do you think you could help with? @Rajesh

Comment: @baao If you see OP has bad naming convention or is using something that might fail later or better practices, would you not recommend them? Like if you see OP using `array.map` without return in callback and manually pushing in array, would you not recommend `.filter` or `.forEach`? For example, `Array.from`  has second args as callback for map. I didn't know that and used to do `Array.from().map()`. So such small things can be pointed out